# Snakes and Letters

Tags: python, beginner, strings, programming-challenge, error-handling

This is the "[Clean up the words](https://www.codeeval.com/browse/205/)" challenge from CodeEval:

> #### Challenge
>
> Given a list of words mixed with extra symbols. Write a program that will clean up the words from extra numbers and symbols.
>
> #### Specifications
>
> 1. The first argument is a path to a file.
> 2. Each line includes a test case.
> 3. Each test case is a list of words.
> 4. Letters are both lowercase and uppercase, and mixed with extra symbols.
> 5. Print the words separated by spaces in lowercase letters.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> 1. The length of a test case together with extra symbols can be in a range from 10 to 100 symbols.
> 2. The number of test cases is 40.
>
> **Input Sample**
>
> ```
> (--9Hello----World...--)  
> Can 0$9 ---you~  
> 13What213are;11you-123+138doing7
> ```
>
> **Output Sample**
>
> ```
> hello world  
> can you  
> what are you doing
> ```

In a [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/131730/no-more-filthy-words?noredirect=1#comment245828_131730) someone joked the program would be much shorter / simpler in Python. I accepted this as a challenge and excuse to practice Python.

**Solution**:

```
import sys
import re

def sanitized(line):
    sanitized_line = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]+", " ", line)
    return sanitized_line.lower().strip()

def main(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as input_file:
        for line in input_file:
            print(sanitized(line))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        file = sys.argv[1]
        main(file)
    except:
        print("No argument provided.")
```

It's so succinct I'm unsure there's enough for a review, but this site surprised me in the past.

Comment: Well, it looks nice. As an alternative to that regex you could also use `re.sub(r'\W+', '', line)`. Apparently I was about to suggest `''.join(ch for ch in string.printable if ch.isalnum())` but in this case using a regex is far better when talking to the speed of processing.

Comment: The `W` regex shortcut won't apply since this also removes numbers. For the same reason `isalpha` is preferable over `isalnum`

Comment: You're right. Talking about the speed of you program, try `re.compile` before actually `sub`ing. IT saves a few `usec`s. Have a quick look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1277047/6165050)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is pretty clear and clean. I will have to do some nit-picking, but here goes an attempt:

- `try` - `except` without the actual exception(s). Here, you print an error when the exception raised is an `IndexError` (to `sys.argv`), but consider that you get the same error message if the file can't be properly opened (or is simply non-existent).

  Change it to `except IndexError`, and let any `IO/OSError` just bubble up, since the corresponding error message is often clear enough (e.g., 'Is a directory', 'File does not exist', etc).
- You're printing the error message to stdout. You could consider exiting using `sys.exit("No argument provided.")`, which will exit with an exit code of 1, and print the message to stderr. Or raise an equivalent exception to the one you're catching.
- 'r'ead mode is the default opening mode. While perhaps clearer with the extra argument, `with open(file) as ...` is more standard.
- In case of Python 2: don't use `file` as a variable name, since it shadows the built-in `file` function. Use e.g. `filename` instead.

Nits:

- Do you want it to be Python 3 only? Otherwise, include a `from __future__ import print_function` at the top. `print` will still work as it is now in Python 2, but once you use more arguments, you're printing a tuple in Python 2, instead of a series of concatenated `str`-ified elements. (Thanks to JoeWallis in the comments for pointing out the mistake that I was thinking "tuple"-wise where it was just a parenthesized string.)
- doc-strings to the program and functions, if you want to go all-out. (A linter would complain about that, even if it's pretty unnecessary here, and not to the point of the exercise.)

Comment: Related to your `try...except` remarks, one should almost never use bare `except:` as per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id48): *A bare `except:` clause will catch `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions, making it harder to interrupt a program with Control-C, and can disguise other problems. If you want to catch all exceptions that signal program errors, use `except Exception:` (bare `except` is equivalent to `except BaseException:`).* It's not a problem here, but one should make it a habit not use bare `except:`.

Comment: @VedranŠego I state it less general (more specific about catching the proper `IndexError`, since that relates to the error message), but aren't we saying the same thing; or do I miss something? Or is your comment for the question, not my answer?

Comment: @Evert I was in doubt whether to put it under the question or here. I opted here, as an additional comment to what you wrote, aimed for the OP.